# Change of variable and diffeomorphic surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose two curves $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are diffeomorphic.

Is the arc-length measure $ds_\gamma$ absolutely continuous to $ds_\gamma'$ with a positive derivative? ($ds_\gamma=\phi\, ds_\gamma'$ for some $\phi\geq 0$)

Does the similar result hold for diffeomorphic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, the change of variables formula holds for diffeomorphisms between smooth Riemannian manifolds (which include as special cases the surfaces and curves in $\mathbb{R}^n$).